# Fetch/filter first item in list of objects matching on a property/key in Python

Tags: python, filter

Given a list:

```
L = [
    {
        'name': 'joe',
        'animal': 'lemur'
    },
    {
        'name': 'pi',
        'animal': 'snake'
    },
    ...
]
```

... suppose I want to pull out the first match for `'animal' = 'snake'`

Is there a clean way to do it?

```
matches = [item for item in L if item['animal']=='snake']
match = matches[0] if matches else None
```

^ This works, but can we do better?

Or suppose our items are objects. Then we would be doing `... if item.animal=='snake'` instead.

I've written the following solution:

```
def first_match(L, **kwargs):
    key = next(iter(kwargs))
    val = kwargs[key]
    matches = [item for item in L if (item[key] if isinstance(item, dict) else getattr(item, key)) == val]
    return matches[0] if matches else None
```

... and it tests ok:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a=a
        self.b=2*a
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.a}, {self.b}'

obs = [C(i) for i in range(3)]
print(first_match(obs, a=1))

dicts = [ {'u':i,'v':10*i} for i in range(3) ]
print(first_match(dicts, v=20))
exit(0)
```

Output:

```
> python test.py 
1, 2
{'u': 2, 'v': 20}
```

... but I'm interested to know if there's a cleaner solution.

If not I'll move some of this into an answer if it makes sense to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe with `next` and a generator and an extra `None` in case of no matches:

```
def first_match(L, **kwargs):
    key = next(iter(kwargs))
    val = kwargs[key]
    match = next(item for item in L if (item[key] if isinstance(item, dict) else getattr(item, key)) == val, None)
    return match
```

For your example code:

```
match = next(item for item in L if item['animal'] == 'snake', None)
```